# Implementing Counting semaphores in java

Tags: java, concurrency, semaphore

I am trying to implement simple counting semaphores to help with concurrency, and when I research the topic more online for the wait(); and signal(); commands I keep seeing comments about how those are built into the java.util.conncurrent.semaphore package.

If this is the case how can I use the commands with integer values for the wait and signal?  Or would I have to create my own wait(); and signal() methods for decrementing/incrementing the integer values stored in the semaphore?

For example:

```
Semaphore count = new Semapore(4);
```

Later on in the class:

```
wait(count);
```

or

```
signal(count);
```

does this work or do I need to define the wait and signal methods myself?

Comment: Are you talking about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#release(int) and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#acquire(int) ?

Comment: I suppose I am.  I guess the examples I encountered all had different syntax or were personalized to suit specific program needs.  Thanks!  I'll just use acquire and release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) for the `Semaphore` class.  The methods you are looking for are called `acquire` and `release` both of them can take integer arguments.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah I guess the examples I looked at had different syntax for custom acquire and release mechanisms